# Powershell: Disable need for elevation?

Tags: powershell

Is there any way to disable the need to run in an elevated context for a powershell script? Anything goes.

I am setting up a test environment and during some of the tests I must reconfigure parts of the OS (notably: an IIS instance) - and windows keeps asking to run the script from an elevated process.

Those are test machines. As such, "anything goes", including turning off UAC - which I did, but PowerShell still asks.

Comment: Did you reboot after turning off UAC?

Comment: If anything goes, why don't you use the `Administrator` account to log on, or just open one elevated PowerShell session and start all your tests from there.

Comment: If you are asking if you can start a non-elevated PowerShell window and then run programs that require elevation without provoking the UAC prompt, then the answer is no. I recommend doing what @PeterHahndorf suggested - just open a PowerShell window that's already elevated (answer UAC prompt just once) and do what you need to do there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setup enviropment variable `__COMPAT_LAYER` to value `RUNASINVOKER` before script runs - it may prevent elevation request if it realy not needed.
This elevation request suppression method described in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2010/09/23/a-self-elevating-powershell-script/), and it's work for me in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling the "User Account Control: Turn on Admin Approval Mode" policy setting?